# Unable to build the TensorFlow model using bazel build

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow-serving

I have set up the TensorFlow server in a docker machine running on a windows machine by following the instructions from https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic. I am successfully able to build and run the mnist_model. However, when I am trying to build the model for the wide_n_deep_tutorial example by running the following command "bazel build //tensorflow_serving/example:wide_n_deep_tutorial.py" the model is not successfully built as there are no files generated in bazel-bin folder.

[image]

Since there is no error message displayed while building the model, I am unable to figure out the problem. I would really appreciate if someone can help me debug and solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the target for wide and deep model in the BUILD file solves the problem.

Added the following to the BUILD file:

```
py_binary(
    name = "wide_n_deep_model",
    srcs = [
        "wide_n_deep_model.py",
    ],
    deps = [
        "//tensorflow_serving/apis:predict_proto_py_pb2",
        "//tensorflow_serving/apis:prediction_service_proto_py_pb2",
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow:tensorflow_py",
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just guessing the command line here as [there is no target in the BUILD file of tensorflow serving for wide_n_deep_tutorial.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/tree/master/tensorflow_serving/example/BUILD).

You can only build mnist and inception targets as of today.

Comment: So I cannot build and run my own model in TensorFlow Serving?